# Is it possible to create a custom PowerPoint PresenterView?

Tags: c#, powerpoint, add-in

I'm wondering if it's possible to change the presenter view of a powerpoint presentation with a custom made addin?

When I say change - I mean completely restructure its look away from this:

[PresenterView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEokz.png)

Comment: Sorry, not currently possible. If such a capability were added, it would most likely be programmable with Office.js, which you can currently use to make custom task panes.

Comment: Yeah, I though so. What do you think about a hacky solution of creating a desktop app that runs above it, or maybe Windows Forms ?